# Powershell - Replace first occurrences of String

Tags: string, powershell, replace

I've searched for a fair amount for the answer but all I get is how I do it with multiple Strings. I'm pretty new to PowerShell but want to know how I can manage to do it.

I simply want to remplace the first occurence of "1" with "2" ... I only can close to it but no more. The code I found was:

```
Get-ChildItem "C:\TEST\1.etxt" | foreach {
$Content = Get-Content $_.fullname
$Content = foreach { $Conten -replace "1","2" }
Set-Content $_.fullname $Content -Force
}
```

The content of the txt is just random: `1 1 1 3 3 1 3 1 3` ... for keeping it simple.

Could someone please explain how I do it with the first occurence and if it is possible and not to time consuming how I can replace for example the 3rd occurrence?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a positive lookahead to find the position of the first `1` and capture everything behind. Then you replace the `1` with `2` and the rest of the string using the capture group `$1`:

```
"1 1 1 3 3 1 3 1 3" -replace '(?=1)1(.*)', '2$1'
```

**Output:**

```
2  1 1 3 3 1 3 1 3
```

---

To caputre the third occurence, you could do something like this:

```
"1 1 1 3 3 1 3 1 3" -replace '(.*?1.*?1.*?)1(.*)', '${1}2$2'
```

**Output:**

```
1 1 2 3 3 1 3 1 3
```

Comment: It does work. Now I just have to find out what exactly every stept does, but I think I will figure out that myself with some research. Thanks you for your response. :)

Answer (score 5):

Same answer as Martin but a bit more simplified so you might better understand it:

```
$R=[Regex]'1'
#R=[Regex]'What to replace'

$R.Replace('1 1 1 3 3 1 3 1 3','2',1)
#R.Replace('Oringinal string', 'Char you replace it with', 'How many')

#Result = '2 1 1 3 3 1 3 1 3'
```

If you want this in a one-liner:

```
([Regex]'1').Replace('1 1 1 3 3 1 3 1 3','2',1)
```

Found this information [here](http://www.techtalkz.com/microsoft-windows-powershell/133372-replace.html).

Comment: Wow, thanks. That I got without thinking to hard. :)