# Replace only first occurrence

Tags: json, regex, powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a PowerShell scripts which replaces

```
"version" : "xxx"
```

with

```
"version" : "myBuildNumber"
```

Now I encountered that I have multiple of these in my file.
I only want to replace the first occurrence.

I tried already [Powershell - Replace first occurrences of String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38123600/powershell-replace-first-occurences-of-string) but it does not work with my regex.

Here's my script:

```
(Get-Content myFile.txt) -replace '(?<pre>"version"[\s]*:[\s]*)(?<V>"[^\"]*")', "`$1`"$Env:BUILD_VERSION`"" | Out-File myFile.txt
```

Comment: Why not, the same approach, just use a DOTALL modifier: `(Get-Content myFile.txt) -replace '(?s)(?<pre>"version"\s*:\s*)(?<V>"[^"]*")(.*)', "\`$1\`"$Env:BUILD_VERSION\`"\`$3" | Out-File myFile.txt`

Comment: Do you try to modify a json?

Comment: Yes,  the project.json from dotnet core

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are patching a JSON file, regex isn't the way to go. Instead you should parse the JSON, access and change the property you want and write it back:

```
$filePath = 'your_Path_To_project.json'
$json = (Get-Content $filePath -raw | ConvertFrom-Json)
$json.version = $Env:BUILD_VERSION
$json | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10 | Set-Content $filePath
```

Comment: By default `ConvertTo-Json` mangles hierarchy levels below 3 into strings. Add something like `-Depth 10` to preserve deeper levels.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Thanks for the hint, didn't thought about that.

Comment: @dknaack You would need to sperate the statements by a semicolon: `$json = (Get-Content 'projectJsonPath.json' -raw | ConvertFrom-Json); $json.version = $Env:BUILD_VERSION; $json | ConvertTo-Json -d | Set-Content 'projectJsonPath.json'` However, I wouldn't use this since it will decrease readability and maintainability and isn't a good practice.... I would instead create a function `Patch-Version` which takes the JSON path and the actual version as parameter to further improve the readability.